# 403- Forbidden for file in PHP for some request

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

My PHP page script is responding with 403-Access forbidden for some http requests while for some requests its responding properly.

### For the below request (By ajax) I'm getting 403-Access forbidden

```html
POST http://xxxx./xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/interaction/practitioner HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2520
Accept: */*
Origin: http://xxx
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.267 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://xxxx./xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/index.php
X-Citrio-Timestamp: Wht/CLSj01IhGLSPNfWemGXwGww= 2016-02-12T17:41:39.961Z
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=c83cae9c3bc88a4b8ff7ea3c3b279a22

{JSON DATA}
```

---

But, another request to same page is responding properly with different JSON DATA.

Means, for a particular data its giving 403-access forbidden and for some data its responding properly.

The php scripts contains 10-20 functions but, both requests are calling the same function.. {Register user with timetable ids.}

Comment: Can you please show the relevant server code? Usually when the server responds with a 403, it's because the server was coded to respond with a 403.

Comment: Is your requests sent from/to the same domain/subdomain ? Maybe you need to use CORS-request.

Comment: Yes... In both requests same file is requested. Only the JSON data is different. Same method is called by both requests... the only difference is that second request(403-Forbidden) is containing some extra data than earlier one(Working fine).

Actually its a client application and working fine at the time of delivery...But now after 2 months this problem occurred...

Comment: Can you test? Just add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` on your server-side script, if it will works, probably, it means that you have to access the script from another domain or subdomain. Hope it helps, however maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Not really a tech answer, but I asked the providers of our shared multi-site reseller hosting if a ModSec rule could be the cause of this, i.e. inconsistent blocking of an ajax POST with a 403 being returned on fail. They (NetHosted: brilliant support, always) had a look at their end and then disabled a couple of ModSec rules they could see were being triggered. That was the fix.